# Detect areas corresponding to RGB

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, image-processing

I have to create a program that takes a video as input
and after processing it has to be composed just from BGR colors.
Were red color is predominant it has to be (0,0,255),where blue is predominate (255,0,0) and for green (0,255,0).Every area where a color is predominant should have that color, not every pixel.
I found something but it works only for one color.

```
Mat redFilter(const Mat& src)
{
Mat redOnly;
    inRange(src, Scalar(0, 0, 1), Scalar(100, 100, 255), redOnly);
}
```

Can you give me some ideas for this project?

Comment: I posted an answer, let me know if that's the result you're looking for. If not, please let me know so we can find a better solution.

Comment: maybe read about HSV color space if Miki's answer isnt what you want

Comment: @Micka taking highest among BGR, or nearest to 0 (red), 60 (green) ,120 (blue) H value is equivalent (aside corner cases, e.g. when S = 0). Do you have another approach in mind? However is hard to tell what OP wants exactly without further details.

Comment: Miki`s answer is very close to what I need but from what i understood, at the end, the picture should be made from compact colours.To make red all the area where red is predominant not just the pixels.I will add further details at the end of the week but I should get something until next cours this is why I already asked about this.Thank you!

Comment: don't forget to notify with @name when you update the question :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the pure blue, red or green color according to the highest among B,G,R values for each pixel.

Image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Load image
    Mat3b img = imread("D:\\SO\\img\\barns.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);

    // Result image with only pure B,G,R values
    Mat3b bgr(img.size());

    for (int r = 0; r < img.rows; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < img.cols; ++c)
        {
            // Take highest among B,G,R
            Vec3b v = img(r,c);
            if (v[0] > v[1] && v[0] > v[2])
            {
                bgr(r, c) = Vec3b(255, 0, 0);
            } 
            else if (v[1] > v[0] && v[1] > v[2])
            {
                bgr(r, c) = Vec3b(0, 255, 0);
            }
            else 
            {
                bgr(r, c) = Vec3b(0, 0, 255);
            }
        }
    }

    imshow("Image", img);
    imshow("Result", bgr);
    waitKey();


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that you might be looking for. http://aishack.in/tutorials/tracking-colored-objects-opencv/

This article talks about segmenting objects of a specific color. You can use the same approach and identify images in red, green and blue. The article goes a step further and figures out "where" the object is as well.

Comment: I can't see how this answers the question. Can you please elaborate?